# React Native 'Modal' Component Not Covering Entire Screen on Android when using Full Screen Theme

Tags: android, react-native

The title says it all. I've edited the styles.xml file (/projectname/android/app/src/res/values/styles.xml) to contain the following:

```html
<resources>
    <!-- Base application theme. -->
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
        <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
        <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
        <item name="android:windowFullscreen">true</item>
        <item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@null</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

This code successfully makes the app fullscreen, removing the Android status bar. However, if I launch a React Native 'Modal' component the modal only extends as far to the top as where the edge of the status bar would have been, leaving a gap the size of a status bar. How would I modify the modal to extend all the way to the top?

Here's a screenshot of the open modal with the gap:

[image: Open modal with gap]

Comment: Did you ever found a solution? I have the exact same issue now.

Comment: @Zri or William did you find solution I am also trying to find solution.

Comment: I am sorry for the late reply. I have used this for android:
https://github.com/Sunhat/react-native-extra-dimensions-android
It may not be compatible with your version of RN, so I think I made some changes on it directly.

Comment: wrap the modal in a View with flex: 1

Comment: try statusBarTranslucent = true in your modal component

Answer (score 13):

you can apply `statusBarTranslucent={true}` to the react native `<Modal>` component like example below

```
<Modal statusBarTranslucent={true}>
//your modal content
<Modal />
```

knowing that, the `statusBarTranslucent={true}` only available for android

Comment: Thanks! It's helped indeed.

Comment: that is the correct answer, solved my issue. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I had tried to use native Android code to hide the StatusBar for a single component it works in other component but when I used it in modal, it just didn't work.

Then, I tried to remove the modal view and use react-navigation's `StackNavigator` to navigate to a specific path and handle the back button using `BackHandler` component and it worked.